# django listview order by model property

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called Lap with a property calculated using data from the table

```
class Lap(models.Model):
    team=models.ForeignKey('Team', models.DO_NOTHING)
    timestamp=models.IntegerField()
    num=models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def laptime(self):
        endtime=self.timestamp
        starttime=Lap.objects.get(team=self.team, num=self.num-1).timestamp)
        return time.timedelta(seconds=endtime-starttime)
```

I am trying to create a listview for the model

```
class FastestLap(ListView):
    model=Lap
    template_name='fastestlaps.html'
    context_object_name='laps'
```

I want to order the list view by the laptime property.

sorting by a column can be done using the `ordering` variable or by creating a `get_queryset` method and doing `queryset.order_by(fieldname)` in that method but I cant find a way to order by the property. How do I order by laptime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Window`, `F` and `Lag` functions and `annotate` so:

```py
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import Lag

# from .models import Lap
# from django.views.generic import ListView

class FastestLap(ListView):
    queryset = Lap.objects.annotate(
        starttime=Window(
            expression=Lag('timestamp', default=0),
            partition_by=['team'],
            order_by=F('num').asc(),
        )
    ).annotate(
        laptime=F('timestamp') - F('starttime')
    ).order_by('laptime')
    template_name = 'fastestlaps.html'
    context_object_name = 'laps'
```

### References:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#lag